# How do i build a classifier out of two already trained classifiers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, nlp

I want to classify text as either positive, negative or neutral. Therefore i build two different SVMs. The first one classifies between negative and positive/neutral and the other one between positive an negative/neutral. If both classifiers disagree the input is neutral. Now i want two combine these two classifiers into a single one which gives an output of wether the text is positive negative or neutral. I heard of the Voting classifier but this doesn't help because it has to be trained afterwards. Is there any way to make a single classifier out of these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial solution (that won't require training) could be the addition of the boolean outputs of the two classifiers in one post processing step, where 0 maps to negative (or negative/neutral) and 1 maps to positive (or positive/neutral) for the individual classifier outputs. The result of the addition is mapped to one in a category of three in the final ensemble output.

```
Output1 | Output2 | Ensemble output
--------------------------------------
  0     |   0     |       0 (Negative)
  0     |   1     |       1 (Neutral)
  1     |   0     |       1 (Neutral)
  1     |   1     |       2 (Positive)
```

Comment: that is actually a really good idea. I didn't think about adding. Thank you!